# Is it normal for my spine to be sticking out when I'm touching my toes?

Tags: exercise

When I strech (toe touching), my back seems to be at a bit of strain, and my spine seems to be  sticking out. Is this normal?

Comment: Hi @john2546, it would be useful if you could edit your question to provide more information regarding whether you have low body weight.  Whether or not there is any pain. Or if you have done something to your spine to make you think there might be a problem.  Also, as this question is more medical I suspect it might get closed.

Comment: @Tracyat2bactive There isn't really much pain, just very very slight strain, and nothing has happened to my spine really, just I'm very inflexible I guess.

Comment: @Tracyat2bactive - If you think it might be closed as medical, why ask for more medically oriented details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean specifically when you say strain. Likely you just have a lack of flexibility in your spine/back.  Consistent stretching and strengthening of your back will likely reduce or possibly even eliminate any significant straining. However, if you're already "in shape" and experiencing strain or the strain is acute/sudden it would be indicative of an injury of some degree.

As far as your spine sticking out, I would consider that normal.  Anatomically speaking, for a person of average to low body fat percentage there is nothing between your spine and skin to hide or cover it. The leaner a person is the more muscles and bone become visible.

Comment: Be careful not to make assumption, you should of asked about low body fat

Comment: @Tracyat2bactive Answer included different scenarios though, not one single assumption.

Comment: @Tracyat2bactive - Low body fat may or may not make a difference. There is very little tissue over the spine, and it takes quite a bit of body fat before spinal ridges become obscure.

Comment: @CourtnyCotten - Different scenarios, but the original question is very vague. There is no definition of what "sticking out" actually means.